# Twilio - strip inbound callerid bits, enable recording and forward call to the original number called

Tags: php, xml, twilio, voice, twilio-twiml

Noob here, I need help with a simple script (php or XML) that strips a portion of the inbound callerid, in Twiml then forwards that call to the original e164 number dialed. Eg. call comes from +16045551212@sip.someprovider.com:5061 - PHP/xml script strips everything off but the e164 number and then twiml  that number. So the resulting outbound  leg would simply be +16045551212.

Since Twilio supports webhooks, we should be able to take in the number, strip the unwanted bit and return a sanitized number for the outbound leg.

I have recording working and if I place a e164 number in statically, it works fine. I am just having trouble with stripping the unwanted but off the sip uri and telling the system to dial that new number.

I tried using {{From}} but that includes the entire from callerid, including the unwanted sip uri bits.

Twiml webhook I am calling from system...

```
<Response>
 <Say> This call will be recorded for quality assurance purposes. Please standby.</Say>
 <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual" callerId="+1xxxxxxxxx">
 <Number>+1xxxxxxxx
 </Number>
</Dial> 
</Response>
```

I would be grateful for any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the `{#e164}` function of TwiML Bins?

[How to use templates with TwiML Bins](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins)

> Execute Built-in Functions The last feature to share is access to
>   built-in functions. The first such built-in function to ship makes it
>   easy to pull a phone number out of parameters and reformat as E.164.
>   This is very helpful when bridging SIP endpoints such as a Polycom
>   phone with the PSTN world.
>
> For example, let's say a Voice call comes in to a SIP Interface with a
>   To value of sip:+15125551212@mydomain.sip.us1.twilio.com. Since the
>   e.164 phone number is embedded in the SIP endpoint's address, you can
>   use the new built-in e164 function to pull out this phone number and
>   craft the proper TwiML to forward the call:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>{{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Alan! I want to do this in code, versus using their twiml bin.

Comment: Also want to learn how to do this in code versus using mustache, my bad for not being more clear.